# When using Resolve to get a type, how do You set a value to an property of that type

Tags: autofac

now I want to
When using Resolve to get a Test, how do I Can set a value to "Name" property of that type

```
public class test 
{
public string Name{get;set;}

public string Text{get;set;

}
```

Register Typt by  Assembly

```
public void Register<T>(Assembly[] assemblies)
        {
            _builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
                .Where(t => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsAbstract)
                .Named<T>(t => t.FullName)
                .AsSelf()
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();
        }
```

Get Type

```
  public T Resolve<T>(string name)
        {
            return _container.ResolveNamed<T>(name);
        }

var t = Resolve<ITest>("Test.Autofac.test");
```

similar

```
var t = new test();
         t.Name="test";
```

At present  ResolveNamed Only constructors seem to be supported,I want to set the property value directly instead of the generic constructor

ResolveNamed(this IComponentContext context, string serviceName, IEnumerable parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, I think what you want is [property injection](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html#property-injection).

You can either register the property value at registration time...

```cs
builder.RegisterType<T>().WithProperty("Name", "value");
```

Or you can pass it at resolve time...

```cs
container.Resolve<T>(new NamedPropertyParameter("Name", "value"));
```

You can use the `NamedPropertyParameter` (just like [all parameters](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/parameters.html)) in a `ResolveNamed<T>` call just like a `Resolve<T>` call.